# how to connect one server to multple clients

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I have done one server and one client communication by using ip address but am stuck with one server multiple communication

```
s=new ServerSocket(77);
ss=s.accept();
icon.displayMessage("New message for you", "Please click here", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);     
os=ss.getOutputStream();
ps=new PrintStream(os);
is=ss.getInputStream();
br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
ps.println(st);
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

on client side

```
 try
 {
 ss=new Socket(ip,77);

}
 catch(Exception e){
 }
 is=ss.getInputStream();
 br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 os=ss.getOutputStream();
 ps=new PrintStream(os);
 ps.println(msg+"  :   "+st1);
```

Comment: First rule: no empty catch blocks! Next, have you tried using threading to allow the server to interact with multiple clients?

Comment: 2nd rule: close all Object in finally block

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
while (true){
    s=new ServerSocket(77);
    ss=s.accept();
    Thread at = new Thread(ss);
    at.start();
}
```

Then the communication to the client happens in the run-method of 'at'.

Answer (score 2):

you should run each session in a separate Thread, like this:

```
static class Session extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    Session(Socket s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            // your code  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(77);
    for (;;) {
        Socket ss = s.accept();
        new Session(ss).start();
    }
}
```

This code is just to explain the idea.